# List all elements, but only one of duplicated elements?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of strings such as

```
words = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'three']
```

I want to create a new list in alphabetical order like

```
newList = ['one', 'three', 'two']
```

Anyone have any solutions? I have seen suggestions that output duplicates, but I cannot figure out how to achieve this particular goal (or maybe I just can't figure out how to google well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw the contents into a `set` to remove duplicates and sort:

```
newList = sorted(set(words))
```

Answer (score 0):

OR maybe this, using `set`:

```
newList=sorted({*words})
```

Answer (score 0):

If Order of elements in **words** is important for you. You can try this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
words = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'three']
w1 = OrderedDict()
for i in words:
    if i in w1:
        w1[i]+=1
    else:
        w1[i] = 1
print(w1.keys())
```